# Missing Right Parenthesis issue

Tags: sql

This is the Query I have written

```
Select C.CUST_NAME,P.PROD_DESCRIP  from Customer C
JOIN (Ord O,OrderItem OT, Product P) ON (C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID AND O.ORD_ID = OT.ORD_ID AND OT.PROD_ID = P.PROD_ID) GROUP BY  C.CUST_NAME ORDER BY OT.ORDITEM_QTY DESC
```

But the issue is it giving me **Right Parenthesis** Missing issue

Comment: If you are using MySQL, you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although that join syntax is allowed in some databases, it is really much clearer to split out the joins:

```
Select C.CUST_NAME, P.PROD_DESCRIP 
from Customer C JOIN 
     Ord O
     on C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID JOIN
     OrderItem OT
     on O.ORD_ID = OT.ORD_ID JOIN
     Product P
     ON OT.PROD_ID = P.PROD_ID
GROUP BY C.CUST_NAME
ORDER BY OT.ORDITEM_QTY DESC;
```

By the way, this probably isn't doing what you think it does.  It is returning a customer name along with an arbitrary `prod_descrip`.  It is then ordering this result by an arbitrary quantity -- perhaps from the same or a different row.

If you want to get the customer name along with the product with the maximum quantity for that customer, you can do this:

```
Select C.CUST_NAME,
       substring_index(group_concat(P.PROD_DESCRIP  order by OT.ORDITEM_QTY desc), ',', 1) as PROD_DESCRIP
from Customer C JOIN 
     Ord O
     on C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID JOIN
     OrderItem OT
     on O.ORD_ID = OT.ORD_ID JOIN
     Product P
     ON OT.PROD_ID = P.PROD_ID
GROUP BY C.CUST_NAME;
```

Note:  If `PROD_DESCRIP` could have a comma then you will want to use a different separator character.

EDIT:

The above is the MySQL solution.  In Oracle, you would do:

```
select CUST_NAME, PROD_DESCRIP
from (Select C.CUST_NAME, P.PROD_DESCRIP,
             row_number() over (partition by C.CUST_NAME order by OT.ORDITEM_QTY desc) as seqnum
      from Customer C JOIN 
           Ord O
           on C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID JOIN
           OrderItem OT
           on O.ORD_ID = OT.ORD_ID JOIN
           Product P
           ON OT.PROD_ID = P.PROD_ID
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is actually the preferred standard SQL solution.  It will work in most databases (SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, and Teradata).

Comment: I am trying it in SQLPLus, The same query worked on SQLITEManager - @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @TerrilThomas . . . If it "worked" then that was by luck.  The query was returning arbitrary product descriptions for each customer.

Comment: That i what i need . But the same is not working with SQL Plus. Could you direct me the issue.  I also tried your solution but it was giving me GROUP BY Clause issue

Comment: Sir could you just point me as to why is it giving me not a GROUP BY Expression

Comment: @TerrilThomas . . . Because I left in the `group by` clause when I had intended to remove it.  The `seqnum = 1` does something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT C.CUST_NAME, P.PROD_DESCRIP 
FROM Customer C
  INNER JOIN Ord O ON C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID
  INNER JOIN OrderItem OT ON O.ORD_ID = OT.ORD_ID
  INNER JOIN Product P ON OT.PROD_ID = P.PROD_ID
GROUP BY C.CUST_NAME 
ORDER BY OT.ORDITEM_QTY DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.CUST_NAME,P.PROD_DESCRIP  
FROM Customer C
JOIN Ord O
  ON C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID
JOIN OrderItem OT
  ON O.ORD_ID = OT.ORD_ID 
JOIN Product P
  ON OT.PROD_ID = P.PROD_ID
GROUP BY C.CUST_NAME 
ORDER BY OT.ORDITEM_QTY DESC
```